# Two-way TLS/HTTPS passthrough via HAProxy

Tags: ssl, tcp, proxy, haproxy, client-certificates

Any suggestions for setting up a proxy between two parties that are doing a two-way TLS connection?

Concept:

```
[Client (dynamic IP)] ==> [Proxy (static IP)] ==> [Server]
[                   ] ====== two-way TLS =======> [      ]
```

The server has proxy's IP address whitelisted.

The proxy only acts as a static IP point in the chain and will not be able to decrypt the data. It is only supposed to forward TCP packets between parties.

My hunch is that HAProxy's tcp mode needs to be leveraged somehow, but I keep missing something.

```
frontend tcp_proxy
    bind *:9000
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    default_backend tcp_proxy_app

backend tcp_proxy_app
    balance roundrobin
    mode tcp
    option ssl-hello-chk
    option tcp-check
    server app1 <server-address>:9100 check
```